# Not able to display tags from an array onto a label tag

Tags: reactjs

I am retrieving data through API with axios and i am facing an issue rendering one array containing tags into a label element :

Here is the JSON

```
{id: 1, header: "Header 1", title: "Title 1", description: "Description 1",…}
card_image: "http://localhost:8000/media/media/images/cards/card1_cMPijRQ.jpg"
description: "Description 1"
header: "Header 1"
id: 1
logo_image: "http://localhost:8000/media/media/images/logos/1_g2pBgUP.png"
main_img: "http://localhost:8000/media/media/images/main/1_sS1Yf60.jpg"
tags: ["Finance", "E-commerce"]
title: "Title 1"
```

I am not able to display tags, in fact it des display once and then when I refresh this error is displayed :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
ProductInfo
C:/personalworkspace/BP/front/src/components/ProductInfo.js:39
  36 |   </div>
  37 | </Grid>
  38 | <Grid item>
> 39 |   <div className="product tags flex container child">
     | ^  40 |     {props.tags.map((tagsList, i) => (
  41 |       <Label size="tiny" as="a" image key={i}>
  42 |         {tagsList}
```

Please note, label is a semantic ui tag.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the remote API, while the request is working, tags is not fulfilled thus undefined. You can use something like this:

```
{(props.tags || []).map((tagsList, i)
```

Or you can use a loader to show up a spinner while the request is pending.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I had a doubt that it was a synchro issue indeed but I am not a front end dev so was not sure.